# How can I use grep in Linux to find lines with multiple matching conditions in a text file?

Tags: shell, grep, text-processing

I'm working on a Linux system and need assistance in finding specific lines within a large text file using the `grep` command.

The criteria for these lines are:

- Inclusion of either 'term1' or 'term2'.
- Exclusion of 'term3'.
- Ending with 'term4' or 'term5'.

I've been trying different `grep` variations but can't seem to fulfill all conditions at once. Could someone help me construct the appropriate `grep` command? Your assistance is much appreciated!

Comment: Use multiple `grep` commands piped together. Use the `-v` option for a not match.

Comment: Something like `grep -E 'term1|term2' FILE | grep -v term3 | grep -E '(term4|term5)$'` but you should provide proper representative input, and corresponding output along with your best attempt - see [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the helpful input. You're absolutely right. Using the grep command with the -E flag allows for extended regular expressions, and when combined with the | operator, it allows for matching multiple terms. @MarkSetchell

Comment: `grep` is a system utility. You should delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or https://superuser.com/ This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pcre of grep with lookahead assertions :

```
grep -P '^(?=.*term[12])(?!.*term3).*term[45]$' <<< 'term2 term1 term5'
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct, it will find `term3 term1 term5` which it should not according to my understanding of the question - because it contains `term3`.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that OP may not be literally searching for `term1`, `term2` - they could be searching for `cat` and `dog`, so writing things like `term[12]` is maybe not the most helpful.

Comment: @MarkSetchell In my test, it does not find `term3 term1 term5`. Have you tried ?

Comment: `term[12]` is just one regular expression, OP could replace with `cat|dog` if need be.

Comment: Yes, I tried it and my grep found it - not sure what's up. As regards the regex, `term[12]` is quite a long way from `cat|dog` for someone asking this question - one is a character set, and the other is an alternation. Anyway, kudos for answering.

Comment: @MarkSetchell What's your `grep` version, mine is `grep (GNU grep) 3.7`, on Ubuntu ?

Comment: I used V3.7 on Alpine.

Comment: I apologise. I mistyped - it does work. 